# Handling a network request response in android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I created an android application to handle network requests using Volley API. I have managed to get a response from the server but I am failing to loop through the different objects of the result JSON and when I add data to a Listview it is only giving me the application's package name with a number added at the end.

### This is the response that I want to handle.

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1637172000,
            "main": {
                "temp": 301.79,
                "feels_like": 300.34,
                "temp_min": 298.24,
                "temp_max": 301.79,
                "pressure": 1008,
                "sea_level": 1008,
                "grnd_level": 854,
                "humidity": 20,
                "temp_kf": 3.55
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 7
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 3.77,
                "deg": 46,
                "gust": 8.98
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0,
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2021-11-17 18:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

### The object model and its fields

```
public class WeatherReportModel {

    private int dt;
    private JSONObject main;
    private JSONArray weather;
    private JSONObject clouds;
    private JSONObject wind;
    private int visibility;
    private double pop;
    private JSONObject sys;
    private String dt_txt;

    public WeatherReportModel(
            int dt, 
            JSONObject main, 
            JSONArray weather, 
            JSONObject clouds, 
            JSONObject wind, 
            int visibility, 
            double pop, 
            JSONObject sys, 
            String dt_txt) {
        this.dt = dt;
        this.main = main;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.clouds = clouds;
        this.wind = wind;
        this.visibility = visibility;
        this.pop = pop;
        this.sys = sys;
        this.dt_txt = dt_txt;
    }
}
```

### This is call back function which fetches the responses and add to the Model's object

```
public void getWeather(VolleyResponseListener forecast) {

        List<WeatherReportModel> weatherReportModels = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray weather_list = response.getJSONArray("list");

                            // get the first item


                            for (int i = 0; i < weather_list.length(); i++) {

                                WeatherReportModel one_day_weather = new WeatherReportModel();

                                JSONObject first_day_from_api = (JSONObject) weather_list.get(i);

                                one_day_weather.setDt(first_day_from_api.getInt("dt"));
                                one_day_weather.setMain(first_day_from_api.getJSONObject("main"));
                                one_day_weather.setWeather(first_day_from_api.getJSONArray("weather"));
                                one_day_weather.setClouds(first_day_from_api.getJSONObject("clouds"));
                                one_day_weather.setWind(first_day_from_api.getJSONObject("wind"));
                                one_day_weather.setVisibility(first_day_from_api.getInt("visibility"));
                                one_day_weather.setPop(first_day_from_api.getLong("pop"));
                                one_day_weather.setSys(first_day_from_api.getJSONObject("sys"));
                                one_day_weather.setDt_txt(first_day_from_api.getString("dt_txt"));

                                weatherReportModels.add(one_day_weather);
                            }

                            forecast.onResponse(weatherReportModels);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //get the property call consolidated weather

        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: Please any help is greatly appreciated i have been stuck for a long time. I  am still learning

Comment: How are you adding the response to the ListView? Could you share that code as well?

Comment: ```ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, weatherReportModels);
                dailyWeather.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);```  I am using this array adapter together with list view i created using the above call back function

Answer (score 0):

Usually, ArrayAdapter when used like this will try to use toString() function to get the value and display it. Try to override the toString in the
`WeatherReportModel` and try again.

Comment: Is the model definition correct I thought it was the other thing that was also making things hard

Comment: LGTM, except you, has provided the constructor but has not used that to initialize the variables. You could remove that constructor and just provide set/get methods

Comment: Alright thank you I will try and update.

Comment: If my solution works, mark it as accepted.